# Cannot access VM after running "systemctl isolate rescue.target"

Tags: vmware-vsphere, systemctl

I have a VM running on VMWare. OS is RHEL 7. 
I ran the following command and the ssh session also terminated.

```
systemctl isolate rescue.target
```

Now I cannot access the server. Even ping doesn't work.
How can I log into the server?

Comment: You should be able to access the console.  Where did you run the systemctl?  On the host or on the guest OS?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: I don't have access to vmware console. I ran systemctl on the RHEL 7 which runs on vmware.

Comment: You will have to contact someone who has access to the console.  It may even be accessible with a browser.  Were you planning to rescue a system without access to the console?

Comment: Well, that was a command I had to run MBSS scan procedure.
System wasn't in trouble. Thanks for the answer. We will contact administrator.

Comment: When you log in as root, never run a command that you don't know.  OTOH, your system is quite secure now.